# Counting Lines from the same InvoiceID before insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm not really sure how to ask the question, so I'll provide an example first.

User captures an invoice with 3 different Inventory Items on the Invoice as following:

```
Item    Qty UnitPrice

Item 1  3   $145
Item 2  2   $478
Item 3  4   $249
```

I have a trigger on the Invoice Table that fires `AFTER INSERT`

During the insert (to my knowledge) only one record gets inserted at a time.

How would I count the amount of lines being inserted even before the insert?

Would the following code suffice?

`SELECT COUNT(InvoiceID) FROM INSERTED WHERE INVOICENUMBER = '1234567'`

Your assistance is appreciated.

Comment: *How would I count the amount of lines being inserted even before the insert* well you'd have to do that before the insert, in the code block that does the insert (which you'll have to provide). Your code is selecting from `INSERTED`, thus data that's already inserted. Remember `AFTER INSERT` triggers fire... after the insert. What's the real problem you are trying to solve? This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I need to do a calculation that includes all the lines, but the calculation would be incorrect if I don't have all the lines...

Comment: I need to sum the quantity of all the lines, then take another amount I get from another table and divide it with that quantity. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: What do you mean all the lines? If you just select from the table, you will have *all the lines* which would be all *inserted* data assuming you aren't filtering them out in a `JOIN` or `WHERE` clause. Basic code based off your last comment would be `(select count(*) from table1) / (select top 1 quantity from table2)` but everything is still too vague here....

Comment: Thanks @scsimon, so if I understand you correctly, I should count the lines from the table after insert and work off that? My problem with that is, does that not mean my trigger will fire 3 times and only on the 3rd fire, I will have the correct values?

Comment: You haven't posted your trigger, but your trigger would fire after the insert transaction is complete. If the transaction inserted 1 row or 100 rows it's only fire once. Not sure why you are hung up on a trigger here... i don't see it's purpose currently and still think you have an XY Problem.

Comment: Thank you @scsimon, I will try what you suggested and if I get stuck, I will ask for advice.

Comment: From your description, it is unclear (for your example) if there is one insert call with three rows, or three insert calls (each with one row). From your Q&A here, it sounds like three insert calls. In that case, you are right that your trigger would fire multiple times, and only the last time would have the correct count. @scsimon is correct, it would be more efficient to handle this count within the program which is calling the inserts, instead of in a trigger. Maybe you don't have control of the program code though (but didn't mention it).

Comment: @tgolisch, you are so correct. Sorry yes, forgot to mention it, I don't have access to the application code, hence I'm trying to breach the gap with a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve it.

Check the following test I did:

Creation of table:

```
create table TempTable  (id int  primary key identity,  InvoiceID   int, Item varchar(50), Qty float);
```

Creation of trigger on this table:

```
create trigger ItemCount on TempTable
after insert
as
begin
    select sum(t.qty) TotalQty from TempTable t join inserted i on t.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
end
```

Inserting values into this table:

```
insert into TempTable   (InvoiceID, Item,Qty)
values                  (3,'Item1',3)
,                       (3,'Item2',2)
,                       (3,'Item3',4)
```

After running the insert, your results is `27`, but it should actually be `9`.

The reason why this happens is due to Scsimon stating not to use a `JOIN` or `WHERE` clause - if I remove the join, my results is also nine, but it will only be correct for the first insert as I need the sum of each InvoiceID.

So I altered the script and found the correct solution:

```
create trigger ItemCount on TempTable
after insert
as
begin
select sum(qty) TotalQty from inserted
end
```

With the above I get a sum of `9`, which is what I wanted.

Thanks to everyone's assistance.